# Point masses and infinite densities

Tags: mass, density, models, volume, point-particles

Point masses are masses who don't have volume. It is said that they are infinitly dense, but I though division by zero is undefined hence you can't define the [density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density) for a point mass because $\rho=m/V$ (and at $V=0$  then $\rho$ is undefined)

So why do physicist like Stephen Hawking and Richard Feynman say that a point mass is infinitely dense?

Answer (score 4):

This is really a footnote to Carl's answer:

As Carl explains, in Mathematics we approach the zero volume/infinite density as a limit and this is a perfectly well defined process. However in Physics we generally don't believe that infinite quantities exist and the occurrence of an infinity is usually a sign that our theory needs modification. In the case of General Relativity it is widely believed that quantum effects will become important at very short scales and these will prevent the volume from becoming zero and the density becoming infinite. At the moment we have no theory of quantum gravity so no-one knows exactly how this will happen.

Comment: so why are we dealing with point masses if they don't exist?

Comment: @I'm-A-Crackpot-QUACK-CRANK: all physical theories are approximate models of reality that break down if pushed beyond their area of validity. So Newton's laws are an approximation that break down at speeds near $c$, special relativity is a better approximation but breaks down for high densities, general relativity is a still better approximation that breaks down when quantum effects become important and so on. The model of a point mass is a useful approximation because we expect quantum effects to become important only at lengths to small for us to measure.

Comment: @I'm-A-Crackpot-QUACK-CRANK: because it's convenient; oftentimes, we're only interested in the center-of-mass coordinate, and internal structure is an unnecessary complication, unknown or out of scope of the theory (eg quantum); of course, sometimes such a simplification *doesn't* work (eg point particles are problematic in classical electrodynamics)

Comment: But mathematics doesn't permit that since m/0 is undefined as my physical sciences teacher said

Comment: @I'm-A-Crackpot-QUACK-CRANK, mathematics permits the delta "function" (distribution) and thus, the point particle model *is* permitted.  That's all that need be said about this.  See, for example:  http://math.mit.edu/classes/18.013A/HTML/chapter28/section03.html

Comment: How can delta function imply that a point masse have infinite density? THAT'S VERY INTERESTING

Answer (score 1):

You need to read up a bit about calculus.  This is a case not only of using an idealized situation (cf. the ancient jokes about assuming a spherical cow with a uniform distribution of milk), but, as with delta functions,  understanding how a function behaves in the limit, rather than its actual value at that limit.
I still recall my first introduction: take the standard parabola y=x^2 and calculate the limit of the intersection of the perpendicular to the parabola as x--> 0 .

So in this case, think of a body with mass M and radius R, and look at the density as R approaches zero (while M remains constant).

Comment: the intersection will be at infinity but since infinity is defined as something that doesn't have a limit then... Please correct my misunderstanding

Comment: @I'm-A-Crackpot-QUACK-CRANK that is not the definition of "infinity" or "infinite."  Again, you need to learn some algebra and calculus.

Comment: i learned algebra and calculus